# localhost is not showing htdocs cotent?

Tags: installation, localhost, xampp

After XAMPP installation was completed I downloaded WordPress, extracted the files from the zipped folder and put them in htdocs XAMPP folder on my local disk.

But when I open the browser and search for localhost it doesn't show me the files for the WordPress installation that I put inside the folder, instead It just continue showing the Welcome to XAMPP page. So I don't know how to install WordPress at this point.

XAMP was running right but I tried to open it as administrator thinking it could maybe solve something but if I do that it shows me this:

```
"Problem detected! Port 8080 in use by "C:\desktop\apache\bin\httpd.exe"!
Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I just want WordPress to be installed but I really don't know how to fix this :/

Comment: it sounds like you're having XAMPP issues not WordPress issues, have you tried using other local dev environment products? XAMPP is just one of thousands of options! Note that we can help you with WordPress programming questions but this isn't a XAMPP support route

Comment: note this might also be a simple mistake such as the WP zip being extracted into a WP subfolder with the same name as the zip, or XAMPP having an `index.html` that wasn't removed